What were the remarked on differences between northern and southern Korea before independence?
Today north and south Korea are extremely different places. The post independence history of the country has created massive and relatively well known differences in the way of life between people across the border.
However, most countries historically have differences between regions. You find historic sources from basically anywhere speaking of the differences between people in different cities- some truthful, lots grossly exaggerated.
So. Korea. Before independence and division what were regarded as the stand out differences between southerners and northerners?
I'm speaking largely in terms of culture here - the economic difference is fairly well known buts its the people I'm curious about.
Are there any sources of interest speaking about this topic?
Asking as a non Korean speaker....

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)  Is there any evidence that there were distinctions? or that they were remarked on?

The dividing line along the 38th parallel north has been decided by US troops on the hurry and without consulting experts. I'd consider it quite unlikely that this arbitrary division coincided with any existing patterns in the Korean society. Later, it turned out that the 38th had been previously discussed as the line for splitting Korea between Japan and pre-revolution Russia. But I'd consider this discussed line very arbitrarily, as well.

I don't mean along the parallel. I mean between northern and southern Korea defined however it was defined - likely in a very flexible and nebulous way. Though I'd be shocked if there wasn't some degree of overlap with the modern Koreas, the far north and far south being part of the respective countries, but that's incidental

My vague recollection is that the North had most of the heavy industry at the time, but could well be wrong.

Yes, the north was a lot more industrial with it being more mountainous and having more of the natural resources. I'm curious what Koreans were saying were the differences in the people, perhaps a lot off this though, you see this sort of commentary a lot in the UK, Japan, Italy, etc...

@HenningKockerbeck - I'd agree with this, although there are geographical considerations. While there's nothing special about the line, its probably true that northern Koreans with lots of Manchurian neighbors had a bit of a different outlook on life than southern ones whose primary external worry was seaborne raids from Japan. As the other comments mentioned, proximity to the Manchurian railway in the north probably made a big for development too.

Good question.  I am not sure about "economic difference is fairly well known" - reading older stuff, like books right after the war, one recurring subject was how poor South Korea was, 1950-ish.  Remember, they'd been brutally occupied by Japan for 50+ years and North Korea might even have been better off if they had less exposure to Japanese troops.
